# AWS single public IP & websockets

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, websocket, server, load-balancing

I need to create an AWS architecture to support an application which needs to be up 100% of the time. In order to achieve fault tolerance I want to create an auto scaling group with a minimum of 2 machines. On all the running servers from the auto scaling group I need to get data from a third party server (using sockets) which accepts only 1 IP on the allowed list. All the public users should be able to open a websocket connection to one of the servers.

Is there any way to connect to the third party server using only one IP? I think that NAT would be a way to do it but then the users won't be able to connect to the servers anymore.
What are some best practices to offer websocket connections through a Load Balancer ?

Please let me know if I didn't give enough details about the context.

Thanks,
Gabriel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several tutorials out there for using websockets through an ELB if you search. It looks like the gist of it is to use TCP load balancing, increase the connection timeout on the ELB, and terminate SSL on the web servers.

As long as you are using websockets through an ELB, I don't see how NAT would interfere with the websockets at all. So using an ELB, and then using a NAT to enable your third-party API calls, should work fine.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use a NAT, have you thought about setting up a single server to proxy those third-party API calls through? If you can send only those API calls through a proxy server then you wouldn't have to worry about the NAT configuration for your other network traffic. The downside is that the proxy server would become a single point of failure.